# How to say "Now it's <something> time!"

Tags: expression

I would like to gather people around an activity such as eating, sport, or drinking. My example is fine?

> Nun es ist Essen Zeit.

Comment: .... aber auch "Essenszeit". Im ganzen Satz: "Nun ist es Essenszeit", "Weihnachtszeit", aber "haben wir Winterzeit".

Comment: Das *es^ ist optional.

Comment: *Essen fassen!*

Comment: I disagree that this is a proofreading or bulk-translation question. The phrase in question is sufficiently idiomatic in English to warrant a dictionary entry.

Comment: Oder "es ist Zeit zu essen" (oder heißt es "es ist Zeit zum Essen"? http://www.googlefight.com/es+ist+zeit+zu+essen-vs-es+ist+zeit+zum+essen.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what kind of time it is there are several possible translations.

Note that also *nun* is the cognate for *now*, the correct translation is *jetzt*. The verb *ist* needs to be in second position as always. The pronoun *es* is usually optional. So the base translation is:

> *Jetzt ist [es] <irgendeine> Zeit.*
>   *Es ist jetzt <irgendeine> Zeit.*

The core phrase *<something> time* can be translated in a number of ways, often several are possible.

> - *Now it’s Miller time.* → *Jetzt ist [es / die] Zeit für [ein] Miller.*
> - *Now it’s lunch time.* → *Jetzt ist (es / die) Zeit fürs Mittag[essen].* *Jetzt ist Mittag[spause].*
> - *Now it’s break time.* → *Jetzt ist (es / die) Zeit für eine Pause.* *Jetzt ist Pause[nzeit].*
> - *Now it’s tea time.* → *Jetzt ist (es / die) Zeit (für Kaffee / zum Kaffeetrinken).* *Jetzt gibt’s Kaffee.*
> - *Now it’s exercise time.* → *Jetzt ist Training.*
> - *Now it’s eating time.* → *Jetzt ist Essenszeit.* *Jetzt ist es Zeit (zu / zum / fürs) essen.*
> - *Now it’s drinking time.* → *Jetzt ist die Zeit [reif] zu[m] trinken.*
> - *Now it’s sleeping time.* → *Jetzt ist Schlafenszeit.* *Jetzt ist es [an der] Zeit, schlafen zu gehen.*
> - *Now it’s bed time.* → *Jetzt ist es Zeit fürs Bett.*

Please note that *jetzt ist Zeit* is ambiguous for it either means *jetzt ist der Zeitpunkt* ‘now is the right time ’ or *jetzt ist genug Zeit* ‘now is enough time’. This ambiguity can be reduced or resolved by the context of course. With *es* it’s always a point in time, with *die* it remains ambiguous.

Comment: In case of doubt: It's five o'clock somewhere.....